# concat Thymeleaf value in html attribute

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I replace "#panel-element-964921" to "#panel-element-${stateOne}" while having the value of "${stateOne}" to show up using Thymeleaf?

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-parent="#panel-790692" href="#panel-element-964921" th:text="${stateOne}">State
        Name</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is `th:href="|#panel-element-${stateOne}|"`

To concatenate plain strings with server-side model attributes one of the easier approaches is to use the `||` symbol wherein we write the complete string with server-side variables embedded within `${varibale}`. This is a common string template feature supported in quite a few programming languages (sadly not in Java)

Then any attributes to be processed by Thymeleaf need to be prepended by `th:`.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could include some explanation in your answer.